# Error Config Route does not have child routes in zend framework 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes, zend-framework2, router

I'm using ZfcUser module for Zend Framework 2
In Controller folder
Controller

```
--UserController.php
--EmployerController.php
```

In module.config.php, I config with route

```
'router' => array(
     'routes' => array(
          'zfcuser' => array(
               'type' => 'Literal',
                'priority' => 1000,
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/user',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'zfcuser',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                     'employer' => array(
                           'type' => 'Literal',
                            'options' => array(
                            'route' => '/employer',
                            'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => 'ZfcUser\Controller\Employer',
                                'action'     => 'index',
                            ),
                        ),
                        'may_terminate' => true,
                        'child_routes' => array(
                             'edit' => array(
                                'type' => 'Segment',
                                'options' => array(
                                    'route' => '/edit[/:id]',
                                    'constraints' => array(
                                        'id' => '[0-9]+'
                                    ),
                                    'defaults' => array(
                                        'controller' => 'ZfcUser\Controller\Employer',
                                        'action' => 'edit'
                                    )
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),
                      ),
                ),  
          ),
     ),
),
```

When I run link: `domain.com/user/employer/edit/1`

=> error: `Route with name "edit" does not have child routes`
=> How to fix it

Comment: try this on any view: <?= $this->url('zfcuser/employer/edit') ?> it may help to debug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you don't need to add the `edit` as a child route in your routing configuration. If I correctly understood your case, `edit` is an `action` so you could just add it as an option in the `employer` route juste like this :

```
'router' => array(
'routes' => array(
    'zfcuser' => array(
        'type'    => 'Literal',
        'options' => array(
            'route'    => '/user',
            'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'zfcuser',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
        ),
        'may_terminate' => true,
        'child_routes' => array(
        'employer' => array(
                'type' => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                'route' => '/employer/[:action[/:id]]',
                'constraints' => array(
                             'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                             'id'=>'[0-9]+'),
                'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'ZfcUser\Controller\Employer',
                            'action'     => 'index',
                         )
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

The arrays indexed by `may_terminate` and `child_routes` should be moved into `employer`